# Unable to read single items from Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a Cosmos DB database named "demo_in_container" containing a container called "resources".

When I query all items with the Javascript SDK, I see my entries.

```
const query = await cosmosClient.database("demo_in_container").container("resources").items.readAll().fetchAll();
console.log(query);
```

I have a single entry with 'wp' as id. The code gives me the following response.

```
FeedResponse {
  resources: [
    {
      id: 'wp',
      containerOptios: [Object],
      _rid: 'CtBUALLmYcEBAAAAAAAAAA==',
      _self: 'dbs/CtBUAA==/colls/CtBUALLmYcE=/docs/CtBUALLmYcEBAAAAAAAAAA==/',
      _etag: '"00009b81-0000-0d00-0000-646533720000"',
[       _attachments: 'attachments/',
      _ts: 1684353906
    }
  ],
  headers: { 'x-ms-request-charge': 2.27, 'x-ms-documentdb-query-metrics': {} },
  hasMoreResults: false
}
```

However, when I try to retrieve a single entry, I get a 404 not found response.

```
const query = await cosmosClient.database("demo_in_container").container("resources").item("wp").read({
      partitionKey: "id",
    });
console.log(query);
```

or

```
const query = await cosmosClient.database("demo_in_container").container("resources").item("wp", "id").read();
    console.log(query);
```

```
ItemResponse {
  resource: undefined,
  statusCode: 404,
  substatus: undefined,
  item: Item {
    container: Container {
      database: [Database],
      id: 'resources',
      clientContext: [ClientContext]
    },
    id: 'wp',
    partitionKey: [ {} ]
  }
}
```

I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Does anyone see the problem?

Comment: Have you tried providing a value for the partition key? You omitted it in your call to `item()`.

Comment: Yes I did, also 404 response

Comment: Please share what is the Container's Partition Key Definition and a code snippet of how you read the item passing the partition key value.